# Is it possible to call Google Analytics Data API (GA4) disabling Google Signals information to avoid thresholds?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-data-api

In a Google Analytics property which is configured to use Google Signals, is it possible to use Google Analytics Data API (GA4) to run reports querying the data without using Google Signals information to avoid [data thresholds](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9383630) ?

It would be very useful to have a flag (Google Signals ON/OFF) to disable it in runReport specific calls without having to completely disable Google Signals for the whole property (and missing the more accurate general Google Analytics reports that Google Signals provides).